# Lyx ModernCV: list inside Entry

Tags: lyx, lists, moderncv

I would like to insert a list inside an entry. There is the section with list but I would like a list inside a description.

example:

```
2001-2006.     Internship blabla 
                           - task description 
                           - task description 2
```

How can I do that in LYX?

thanks

Comment: Next to the four list icons you'll find "increase depth Alt-Shift-Right". Press Return after blabla, than increase depth, turn on another list.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I solved the Problem with adding an Entry and listitems to the entry:

```
\cventry{10.2016-03.2017}{Bachelorarbeit}{Infineon Technologies}{München}{}{ ''Definition und Design einer schnellen programmierbaren elektronischen
DC Last''}
\cvlistitem{Definition der Projektanforderungen }
\cvlistitem{Entwurf und Implementierung des Konzeptes der Steuerung der Last
und der Benutzeroberfläche }
```

this was the output:

[image: Output]

PS: I did the whole thing in Lyx , I copied the Latex code. In Lyx just choose *entry* and *listitem*

I hope this helps :) ah and ignore the german ;)